# Black spots along the veins of avocado leaves

Tags: avocado

[image]

Dear gardening enthusiasts,

I'd like to ask for your advice. My 3-year-old avocado, planted in a pot, has some problems, please see attached photo of one of its leaves, both sides. Since several days I began to notice these black spots accumulating along the leaves' veins, then the leaves turn brownish and fall off. The avocado has already lost several leaves.

A Google-search gave no results, maybe some of you have experienced similar problems and could share your experience.

Comment: Can you add a picture of the whole plant, including the pot, please?

Answer (score 1):

I can see black deposits on the underside of the leaf in the top picture - the black along the rib on the topside appears to be in the same place as the insects on the back. I can't tell what they are, the photo doesn't get clearer under magnification, but it could be blackfly or mites or something, have a look with a magnifying glass. Some kind of insecticide treatment is called for - neem might work, but best to determine quite what the insect is.